# Convert a boxplot to a scatter plot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I currently have a box plot which plots cgpa vs totalScore for the subject 'Mathematics'. Here is the code for the box plot:

`a = sns.boxplot(data=masterdata[masterdata.courseName == "Mathematics"], x = "totalScore", y="cgpa")`

How can I transform the box plot I have to a scatter plot? I don't know how to select the specific subject of 'Mathematics' in the scatter plot. Scatter plots just have x-label, y-label and hue. But how do I plot for "Mathematics" only, like I did in the box plot I have? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to here https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html scatter plot also have a data parameter. so you should be able to do like you did before.

```
 b = sns.regplot(data = masterdata[masterdata.courseName == "Mathematics"],x="totalscore", y="cgpa")
```